# How much free storage space is necessary to stop receiving camera warning?

Tags: internal-storage, camera, storage

I'm trying to use the camera on my android phone but for a while I've had low storage and been getting the message "your internal storage is running out of space".

I have about 20MB free but am still receiving this warning. I even receive this warning with 50mb. How much space do I need to free up before this message goes away and is there any way to bypass or ignore as I know a couple of HD pictures aren't going to use up 15mb.

I'm using a fairly old version of android, don't know the exact one but it isn't really relevant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As camera needs memory to run as well as memory to store images. So if you can afford memory of 200 mb or more, your camera can run well. Every application you run takes some memory.

Comment: You're talking about RAM, I'm talking about non volatile storage